# Why won't my Windows 7 machine boot?

Tags: windows-7, boot, sfc

A couple of months ago, my Win7 PC unexpectedly became unable to boot normally. I'm able to boot into the various Safe Modes, but everything else fails (including what is sometimes called a "clean boot," in which msconfig.exe is used to disable non-essential drivers, services, and programs).

The last time I used my PC normally, I played Skyrim for a few hours and then shut down normally. I use my PC for gaming only, and hadn't really installed any new software in 4 or 5 months.

When I attempt to boot, I get the "Starting Windows" screen with the pulsing logo, and then after a couple of seconds the screen goes black and the mobo BIOS screen reappears -- the computer has just rebooted. Just before the screen goes dark, there is a quiet but distinct "click" sound from inside the tower. It is not an unusual sound -- there are several large fans and 4 or 5 HDDs in there, and the machine has always made a lot of interesting noises while booting -- but its proximity to the failure is suggestive.

I've been fixing my own Win machines for a long time, but after 2 months of experimenting every weekend, I'm out of ideas. I've got a [CBS.log](https://gist.github.com/tomprogers/3e541c6cece4c9d95872335dc03b9e9c) file that purports to describe the problems that couldn't be fixed by the System File Checker, but nothing inside looks serious. And while the log suggests that repair completed successfully, stdout says otherwise:

```
C:\Windows\system32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.
Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.
Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example
C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log
```

I've read that `sfc` needs to be run several times to accomplish its work. I've run it literally dozens of times, and every time it says it was unable to fix some of the problems it found. I've examined a lot of these logs, and it's not actually clear that anything is being accomplished -- the number of work items appears to be roughly constant over time (I have not counted carefully). At this point, the only reason I run `sfc` at all is that it's the only tool that finds problems, and it's the most verbose of the system recovery tools available without booting normally.

I have already run `chkdsk`, but it found no errors.

I have attempted to repair my boot sector and MBR, based on a cryptic, once-only error code seen during System Recovery (I don't recall the error code). It did not fix the problem, but for several hours I was forced to boot from the Win7 install disc, until I successfully repaired the damage I had done (I think). I think this suggests that the boot sector & MBR are fine.

I have uninstalled my graphics drivers (nVidia).

Automatic Windows Update is disabled. I personally inspect every available update before downloading and installing it. I stay on top of it, and generally only refuse updates that are about Win8 readiness.

I tried to do a "repair installation" of Win7 from the DVD, but it refuses to do that from Safe Mode (which really makes me wonder WTF the point is -- medicine that only healthy people can take?).

At this point, I really feel like I need someone to hold my hand; I've done an extensive amount of research and experimentation with the various recovery strategies that are mentioned online, and none of them has made a difference.

I'm attempting to boot Win7 Home Premium (64-bit) SP1 from a 60GB SSD (7.5 GB free).

Any help is appreciated.

**-- UPDATE --**

I tested booting the PC with all drives disconnected except the primary, and it still failed.

I booted the machine using an Ubuntu Live USB, and used Disk Utility to inspect the boot disk. It reports the disk is healthy, and shows three partitions:

1. 105 MB FAT "EFI System Partition"
2. 134 MB "Microsoft Reserved Partition"
3. 64 GB NTFS "Linux Basic Data Partition"

When I run "Check Filesystem" on each parition, both 1 & 2 are described as "clean," but 3 is described as "not clean."

More about partition 3:

- Overall assessment: Disk is healthy
- Power Cycles: 2819
- Bad Sectors: None
- All but one of the various error metrics are at 0; there are 31 "Data Address Mark Errors"

I ran the extended SMART Self-test, and none of these values changed, and the disk is still reported as "healthy."

Based on this [SE thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112150/how-to-correctly-fix-a-dirty-ntfs-partition-without-using-chkdsk), I ran `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda`, but it failed with really interesting information:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

I've already run chkdsk on the drive about 15 times, and each time it completes successfully with no errors.

What do I do next?

**-- UPDATE --**

From my Ubuntu Live USB stick, I am able to mount and explore both the EFI partition and the large main one. The Disk Utility GUI doesn't present an option to mount the other one, and I assume that a "Microsoft Reserved Partition" probably won't play well with *nix.

Days spent researching "NTFS signature" have not proved helpful.

**-- UPDATE --**

The "NTFS signature" issue appears to be unrelated. I was specifying the wrong device (`/dev/sda` instead of `/dev/sda3`). When I corrected the command, `ntfsfix` ran successfully. The boot problem is not fixed, however.

I've since removed my video cards, and now I see a BSOD where the screen used to be blank. The message is:

```
STOP: c000007b {Bad Image}
Exception Processing Message c000007b Parameters 19b6aa0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Edit your question and add more details plus a link to the file, also edit the title to reflect the real question. This is the right place for that type of question.

Comment: The click may be an indication of a HD failure. Are your HDs spinning disks or SSDs? I would fire up a Linux live CD to read the SMART data off the HD(s).

Comment: look inside the CBS.log which files can't be restored.

Comment: What's your HDD and SSD structures? Are they in RAID mode or ACHI mode?

Comment: @NathanAdams: the primary drive where Windows installed is an SSD. None of the other drives are needed, and (normally) the PC can be started without them attached. I'll investigate reading the SMART data anyway.

Comment: @Tom: I think the answer is neither. I'm not using the drives for redundancy, each one is unique.

Comment: @magicandre1981: I'm not certain I'm interpreting the log correctly. There are three unique file names that are listed as "cannot be repaired":
- setup_wm.exe
- telemetry.ASM-WindowsDefault.json
- utc.app.json

This is confusing because: (1) none of those files seem critical to startup; and (2) none of the other hundreds of items ever get repaired, despite running `sfc` upwards of 50 times. I've tried to restore these files manually by extracting them from the DVD, but I could only find one of them, and `sfc` hated it, too. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: those files are not boot relevant, so the issue comes from somewhere else. try to boot a linux Live DVD and see what happens. Does it also reboot the PC?

Comment: Oh, @Tom: my drives are in ACHI mode.

Comment: If you have a Win7 boot DVD or USB, you could do the "repair installation" by booting from it.

Comment: ntfsfix needs an NTFS partition not a block device, try:

    sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda#

or

    sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/sda#

Comment: 1 Have you tried cloning the drive to another disk using a free tool such as clonezilla for windows? If you can't clone could point to hardware failure. If you can clone, your chkdsk /r or sfc /scannow may be more fruitful. 2  for smart attributes you want to look at crc error or read retries. Every disk is different and it may be hard to interpret values. 3 can you review your event viewer logs at all? That may give you more details filtered on error warnings

Comment: Don't run `ntfsfix` against `/dev/sda` !  That's the whole disk - you'll corrupt your drive.  Only run it against your NTFS partition, which sounds like is `sda3`.

Comment: @harrymc: I do have the Win7 install DVD, but I'm not allowed to perform a repair installation. When I try, it tells me that I need to use an install disc that matches the OS. This is the disc I installed from: Win 7 Home Premium x64 with SP1, and that's what is on the drive. Other things I've read suggest that a true repair install can only be performed from a normal boot of Windows, which obv defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Sun: I haven't tried that, but I seriously doubt a hardware failure: repeated runs of `chkdsk` turned up nothing, and the SMART data I found via Linux Live stick didn't show any signs of degradation. Also, I don't have a spare drive large enough to clone this one to. Are there other kinds of hardware you suspect?

Comment: Then your install disc really does not match - Startup repair will work from the boot CD. Perhaps your CD dates from before SP1. For booting, see for example [this article](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN151680/en) for how. For downloading a Windows 7 ISO see [this article](http://www.techfleece.com/2015/12/23/download-official-isos-of-windows-7-windows-8-1-or-windows-10-legally-and-for-free/).

Comment: @harrymc: I doubt that. The disc has "Includes Service Pack 1" printed directly on the disc. I built the computer myself, and installed Win7 from this very disc. I think it is much more likely that the comparison logic is faulty.

Comment: The comparison logic is never faulty, but the Windows installation can be destroyed. I suggest to backup your data and reinstall Windows from scratch. I would suggest first to re-format the disk with slow formatting, just in case.

Comment: Can you do 2 things and report back? 
1. Install HDTune as a trial, run it and report back the findings in the Health  tab?
2. Press F8 during boot, get to the boot menu, select and click 'Disable automatic startup on a system failure' and restart. After that if it crashes it will show a BSOD instead. Report back what you see (exactly).

Comment: And can you boot to command line from the installation DVD and run `sfc /scannow /offbootdir=C:\ /offwindir=C:\windows` ?  See http://www.pcgamer.com/how-to-repair-a-faulty-windows-installation-without-reformatting/ &  http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-resource-protection-found-corrupt-files

Comment: One thing that gets updated by itself and can cause troubles is the antivirus software.

Comment: @Epoxy: I've already reported a STOP code of `c000007b {Bad Image}`; see the final section of my question. HDTune reported "Ok" for all metrics; every metric had Current=100 Worst=100, except "(AD) (unknown attribute)" and "(CA) TA Counter Increased", which both reported Current=69 Worst=69. HDTune's Error Scan found 0.0% bad sectors. I _really_ think "hardware fault" is a dead-end here.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal: I've run `sfc` 30+ times: `set WINDOWS_TRACING_LOGFILE=D:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.33.log` and `sfc /scannow /offbootdir=d:\ /offwindir=d:\windows`. The output: `Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log`

I guess `sfc` must be run multiple times, so I ran it 3 times for you. Each run created 3,519 new files in `C:\Windows\winsxs\Temp\PendingRenames`.

[log](http://bit.ly/1TKIp8y) [log](http://bit.ly/1UvC0QW) [log](http://bit.ly/25BQ9os)

Comment: @Tom no need to run it just for me :-] I just wanted to suggest to use `sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=d:\windows` -to use the DVD media as a source for SFC when it fails using your installation as a store. So `offbootdir` would be your install media. Because you get errors there: `Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"setup_wm.exe"... `

Comment: `but after 2 months of experimenting every weekend` - that is a horrible amount of time, you should reinstall instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you are presented with the boot menu, there should be an option to stop the computer from automatically rebooting.  Enable it and try booting normally into Windows.  If done correctly, the machine will not reboot automatically and instead will display a blue screen with a STOP error code at the very top.  That code is essential to correctly diagnosing this problem.

Comment: I wasn't able to find that setting anywhere in the UEFI menus, but I did find it in Windows Advanced System Settings > System Startup and Recovery. With automatic restart disabled, the Starting Windows screen appears for a few seconds, then goes blank and stays blank indefinitely (>20 minutes). All HDD activity stops moments after the screen goes blank. No memory.dmp file was created (I looked for it afterward in Safe Mode).

Comment: I removed my video cards and now I see a BSOD where the screen used to be blank. The message is `STOP: c000007b {Bad Image}
Exception Processing Message c000007b Parameters 19b6aa0 0 0 0`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is clearly a 'rogue' driver...

You have try most of the advice I could have give you...

Now you have to become a bit radical to solve the problem...

```
1. Boot in security mode (or better boot from a alternative OS)
2. make a backup folder to move/save some driver files
3. locate your c:\windows\system32\drivers folder
4. order files by date, and move a few "dates" to the backup folder
```

Now try to reboot...
If problem persists, put back the 'saved' files
and do the same process for the next 'dates'

Hope you'll solve it...

Comment: No good. The most-recently modified file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\` is dated 2015-12-04 -- two months before the problem occurred. Thanks, tho!

Answer (score 0):

From what I read I am pretty confident that you should try cloning the drive to another disk (as somebody already suggested) and if this fails then SpinRite will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

According to your information, when booting from the same Windows 7 SP1 CD
which you used to install Windows, you get the error message that you
need to use an install disc that matches the installed OS.

I take it to mean that the Windows installation was destroyed.
A difference of one byte can be the difference between a Windows installation
being recognized or not, so you have at least one bad sector on the hard disk.

I would suggest to backup your data and reinstall Windows from scratch.
You should first re-format the disk with slow formatting, which will mark
bad sectors and reinitialize the magnetic signatures of the sectors.
If problems still occur, a new hard disk might be in order.

Comment: `reinitialize the magnetic signatures of the sectors` ? OP wrote: I'm attempting to boot Win7 Home Premium (64-bit) SP1 from a 60GB SSD (7.5 GB free)

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal: Right - formatting does not apply to SSD. To reinitialize an SSD see for example this article : [How To Securely Erase Your SSD Without Destroying It](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/securely-erase-ssd-without-destroying/), which should only be done in extreme cases. In the case here, a quick format should be enough.

Comment: I've run `chkdsk` dozens of times while troubleshooting, finding 0 bad sectors. HDTune also reported 0 bad sectors found, and the SMART data from the drive does not suggest there have been any failures now or in the past. This seems to falsify your inference that there are any bad sectors on the disk. Presumably, the solution would be finding that "one bad byte" and re-writing it, and I assume this is _precisely_ what `sfc` is for. The fact that it consistently fails not only to fix the problem but even to improve the situation suggests there is a larger problem... _somewhere._

Comment: Bad data does not always imply bad sector, which might be what is happening in your case. My advice is not to look for the bad byte(s) but to move on.

Comment: How did this end?

Comment: @Vitas: Who knows ?